# calculating 3D coordinates from a flattened 3D array

Tags: c++, matrix, coordinates, linear-algebra

I have a linear index, flattened in column major order, and I like to get back the 3D coordinates [x,y,z]. I found this for row major https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19765/calculating-coordinates-from-a-flattened-3d-array-when-you-know-the-size-index , but can't figure out the column major?

Comment: It will help to draw a diagram.

Comment: The post you linked to has the formula in column major order. See [this diagram at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order#/media/File:Row_and_column_major_order.svg).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given

```
sometype array[XSIZE][YSIZE][ZSIZE];
```

then as a 1-dimension array, then if you have 
x >= 0 and x < XSIZE, y >= 0 and y < YSIZE and z >= 0 and z < ZSIZE, then

```
Index = ((x * YSIZE + y) * ZSIZE) + z;      // Row major order, C/C++
Index = ((z * YSIZE + y) * XSIZE) + x;      // Col major order
```

and for calculating the Index, given x, y, z:

```
// For Row major order
z = Index % ZSIZE;
y = (Index / ZSIZE) % YSIZE;
x = Index / (ZSIZE * YSIZE);

// For Col major order
x = Index % XSIZE;
y = (Index / XSIZE) % YSIZE;
z = Index / (XSIZE * YSIZE);
```

Comment: Is there any general formulation for n-D array?

Comment: Yes. Given array a[N1][N2}[N3]...[NN} then viewing as 1-dimensional array
and access element a[m1][m2][m3]...[mn]
Index = (((.. (m1 * N2 + m2) * N3 + m3) * N4 + m4) * .... + aN;
and 
mN = Index % NN;
mN-1 = (Index / NN) % NN-1;
:
m1 = Index  / (NN * N(N-1) * N(N-2) * N2);  // where  (N-n) are to read as subscripts